# Overriding Method with Generic Parameters from Abstract Class

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I am unable to compile a method which needs to override a method from an abstract class supertype which uses generics for one of the parameters.  The compiler complains that the extending class' setRef() method does not override a method from the supertype.

Parent Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AbsClass<Q extends Interf> {
    public abstract Ref<? extends AbsClass<Q>> getRef();
    public abstract <M extends AbsClass<Q>> void setRef(Ref<M> newRef);
}
```

Ref is:

```
public interface Ref<M extends AbsClass<? extends Interf>> { }
```

and Interf is:

```
public interface Interf { }
```

Extending Child Class (setRef() doesn't compile):

```
public class ChildClass extends AbsClass<InterfImpl> {
    @Override
    public Ref<ChildClass> getRef() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <M extends ChildClass> void setRef(Ref<M> newRef) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have also tried using wildcards, and received same error.  With wildcards, the abstract class' setRef() is:

```
public abstract void setRef(Ref<? extends AbsClass<Q>> newRef);
```

and the extending class' setRef() is:

```
public void setRef(Ref<ChildClass> newRef)
```

or even:

```
public void setRef(Ref<? extends ChildClass> newRef)
```

The only way I can get it to compile is if the extending class' setRef() uses the abstract class' type:

```
public <M extends AbsClass<Interf>> void setRef(Ref<M> newRef)
```

But I would like to limit the typing of the newRef parameter to be `Ref<ChildClass>` or subtypes, so this isn't perfect.  How can I get my extending class to only allow ChildClass or its subtypes for the setRef() method's newRef parameter?  Part of my confusion is that the ChildClass' getRef() return value handles the generic typing just fine, and the same "signature" on setRef()'s parameters fails to compile.  Help?  Thanks!

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: @Tim, he is talking about compile time error.

Comment: Right, no stacktrace, just compiler error of: "The method setRef(Ref<ChildClass>) of type ChildClass must override or implement a supertype method."  This is from the `public void setRef(Ref<ChildClass> newRef)` form of the method declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `setRef` is that you could access an instance of `ChildClass` through a variable of type `AbsClass<? extends Interf>` and thus the parameter type for `setRef` would look like `<M extends AbsClass<? extends Interf>>` which again could be any `M` but which also doesn't match `<M extends AbsClass<Q>>` since `Q` has been defined to be `InterfImpl` in your case.

You could change `ChildClass` to this:

```
public <M extends AbsClass<InterfImpl>> void setRef(Ref<M> newRef)
```

but this would still allow any `M` and you can't just use `Ref<ChildClass>` because what I said above, i.e. the compiler wouldn't know about `Ref<ChildClass>` if you used a variable of type `AbsClass<InterfImpl>` or even `AbsClass<? extends InterfImpl>`.

One way to allow only for `ChildClass` parameters would be to use `ChildClass` in the generic type as well, e.g. like this:

```
public abstract class AbsClass<Q extends Interf, M extends AbsClass<Q, M>> {
  public abstract Ref<M> getRef();
  public abstract void setRef(Ref<M> newRef);
}

public class ChildClass extends AbsClass<InterfImpl, ChildClass> {

  public Ref<ChildClass> getRef() { return null; }

  public void setRef(Ref<ChildClass> newRef) { }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you for the rapid and thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because in `AbsClass.setRef()`, your parameter is of type `Ref<? extends AbsClass<Q>>`

But in your `ChildClass.setRef()` the parameter is of type `Ref<? extends ChildClass>`.

For overriding, a subclass should have the same typed parameters in the method as it's parent (before type erasure when using Generics).

Comment: I think I understand that, but since `ChildClass extends AbsClass<InterfImpl>` doesn't that match the `<? extends AbsClass<Q>>` in its parent?

Comment: @BrianFrutchey the problem is that `<? extends AbsClass<Q>>` might match much more and the compiler can't narrow that down to `ChildClass`.